# How to see what javascript events are binded to a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, events, binding, firebug

I'm trying to see how this page handle its click events for the left side menu.
http://sg.jobsdb.com/SG/jobs/accounting/1?JSSRC=HPJC

Using Firebug, I could see the click object but couldn't make any sense of how it displays the content on the right side.

Are there any ways I could see the source code the binds the event to the element without searching through all the scripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome debugger has got what you're looking for

```
isAttribute: false
lineNumber: 348
listenerBody: "function (){return typeof jQuery!=="undefined"&&!jQuery.event.triggered?jQuery.event.handle.apply(arguments.callee.elem,arguments):undefined;}"
node: HTMLTableCellElement
sourceName: "http://content.jobsdb.com.sg/Content/v50/Javascript/JobsDB.combined.min.js"
type: "click"
useCapture: false
```

I used to be all about firebug but the chrome debugger has definitely caught up in my opinion, and with the [new improvements coming down the pipe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&feature=player_embedded) I don't think I'm going back to firebug anytime soon.